# exponential convergence of an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose I have a sequence of nonnegative numbers $\{x_0,x_1,\dots\}$ with the properties that

1. The sum $x_0+x_1+\cdots$ converges.
2. There exists some $0 \le \rho < 1$ such that
   $(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{k+1}) \le \rho( x_0 + x_1 + \dots + x_k )
   \quad\text{for }k=0,1,\dots$

I would like to know what the second property allows me to conclude about the **rate** at which $x_k\to 0$. Ideally, I would like to prove an exponential bound of the form $x_k \le c \rho^k x_0$ for all $k$ (where $c$ may depend on $\rho$ but does not depend on the choice of sequence). For example, the sequence $\{\rho^k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ decays exponentially and satisfies properties 1 and 2, but I don't know if the converse holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second condition is equivalent to 
$$x_0 + x_1 + \cdots + x_k \leq \frac{1}{1-\rho} \left(\rho x_0 - x_{k+1} \right)+x_0.$$
As $k \to \infty$ all this establishes is an upper bound on the sum dependent on $x_0$. So pick $x_0$ large enough so that $\sup_{k > 0} |x_k|$ is small relatively and the above inequality will hold regardless of the rate of convergence. So this condition is meaningless in determining anything about the convergence rate of the sum.

Given this, it is somewhat pointless to try to answer the rest of your question. You might as well say that the sums that converge exponentially are the ones that converge exponentially. I could only guess at what you really want. I like that you are making conjectures, though. Perhaps you can modify your second condition? Is there any real reason you have for it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. What I meant to say was that I want to know something about the rate at which $x_k\to 0$. I reformulated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @LaurentLessard My first paragraph still applies. Given any sequence, redefining $x_0$ will guarantee that your condition holds. This means essentially it doesn't matter what the sequence is at all and the second condition will tell you absolutely nothing about the rate of convergence, for the sum or each term.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying now. e.g. I could choose the sequence $x_0=1$, $x_1=\dots=x_m=0$, $x_{m+k} = \rho^k$ for $k=1,2,\dots$. All such sequences have the same sum and satisfy both conditions, but no $c$ is large enough to exponentially bound each terms; I can just keep increasing $m$.

Comment: @LaurentLessard, yes that is one problem. I actually didn't read your question carefully enough to realize you wanted a uniform bound (that is $c$ independent of the sequence). But there is even more of a problem. Let $x_k = 1/k^2$ for $k> 0$. Define $x_0 = 1000$. For $\rho = 1/2$ convince yourself that it satisfies the second condition. See the problem?